# How to make conditions with CASE WHEN in SphinxQL?

Tags: php, mysql, search, sphinx

How can I set condition for Sphinx search? In my custom MySQL code, which is as followed.

How can I re-code it as Sphinx search?

```
$condition = "(CASE WHEN related_type ='Course' THEN related_id = 1 
              ELSE related_id IN(2,3,4)
              END)";
```

Answer (score 1):

SphinxQL has an `IF()` function that can be used in similar fashion.

For example:

```
 SELECT *, IF(related_type='Course', related_id=1, IN(related_id, 2,3,4) ) AS filter 
      FROM myindex WHERE filter = 1
```

Functions need to be in the `SELECT` part, not in `WHERE`

(also note the slightly different syntax for `IN()`. In sphinx it's a function)

Comment: This is a filter for where condition. But how we fetch a field value based on a case as we do with CASE WHEN in mysql?

Comment: Well **Fields** need to be matched in the **full-text query**. So would have ot form a suitable query, and then put in the `MATCH(..)` query. full-text queries can't depend on **attributes**, so would have to make sure all the values are stored in Fields.